# Passing a string argument to ifstream

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to pass a string argument to a function from the main function and then passing this received string argument to ifstream constructor. I'm able to receive this string in the function, but when I pass this argument to ifstream, I get a error message:

no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream(const string&)’
  std::ifstream file(fileName);

Here is my code:

```
int** read_CSV(std::string const& fileName)
{

 //cout<<fileName<<"\n";//this works

 std::ifstream file(fileName);//problem

 //Rest of logic
}
```

The main function:

```
int main()
{

 int** inputMatrix1 = read_CSV("inputData4_80-20_100x32.csv");

 return 0;
}
```

The variable fileName is creating the problem. If I pass it as it is, it gives the error. But instead, if I explicitly mention the name of the file using string rather than the variable, the code works fine. Can someone explain what exactly is the problem here and how I can solve it?

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? With versions before 5 (which are quite old by now)  you have to explicitly enable C++11 mode.

Comment: Refer to [`std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) : the specific constructor you need has been added in C++11, so you need a C++11 compatible compiler (and run it in C++11 mode)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm currently using GCC version 5.4.0

Comment: Before C++11, it was necessary to do `std::ifstream file(fileName.c_str())`, since `std::ifstream` did not have a constructor that accepted a `std::string` as an argument,   Since C++11, `std::ifstream` has a constructor which accepts a `std::string` as the first argument, so your code will work.

Comment: Then your code should work, as series 5 of GCC enabled C++11 by default. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output of that MCVE.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Are you sure that gcc 5.x enables c++11 by default? I think it started with gcc 6. This does not compile in godbolt (https://godbolt.org/g/W1bXTA) with gcc 5.4 without `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @Peter using c_str did solve the problem.

Comment: @archity You likely need to compile with `-std=c++11` to enable C++11 support (which includes the overloaded constructor for `std::ifstream`).

Comment: @Holt Yes, I will have to explicitly use the c++11  tagline in order to use it with g++.

Comment: @Holt Okay it was a misunderstanding from my side. The 5 series does not use C++11 by default, but still the old `-std=gnu++98`. So a proper solution for the OP would not be to use `c_str()` but rather to add the `-std=c++11` flag (or optionally `-std=gnu++11` if GCC extensions are wanted).

Comment: @Peter You can put the c_str as the answer to the question, explaining about the c++11 compiling too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was that I was trying to compile without C++11 standard using just g++ "NameOfFile.cpp". There are 2 possible solutions to the problem, from the comment section, and they are as follows:

1. Using -std=c++11 when giving the command for compilation. The resultant compilation command would look as follows:
   `g++ -std=c++11 "NameOfFile.cpp"`
2. Another solution, as pointed out by @Peter, is to use `c_str()` at the end of the string object, since the ifstream doesn't accept strings as an argument before c++11, so `c_str()` is used for explicitly converting to a compatible format.

Here's the modified code line for the second solution:
`std::ifstream file(fileName.c_str());`

Thanks to @Peter and @Holt for their inputs.